# Firebase Auth works without Google Services now. Will it work in China?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase Auth is working without Google Services for now. It was written in official blog:
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/10/firebase-auth-android-non-gms.html

Does it mean that Firebase Auth will work in mainland China from now?

How can we check it?

Answer (score 1):

The change described in the blog has nothing to do with network connectivity from China.  It is just decoupling Firebase Auth from Play services so that it's no longer required on the device.